# How can I make a new copy of kube_namespace_labels metric with a different name during scraping and add prefix to labels?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

kube_namespace_labels is a metric that scrapes all the namespace labels.

I want a new copy of it with a different name and a prefix added to the labels.

For example, if this is what the metric looks like:

`kube_namespace_labels{namespace="ns1",label1="value1",label2="value2"}`

I want the copy to look like this:
`kube_namespace_labels_copy{namespace="ns1",prefix_label1="value1",prefix_label2="value2"}`

I am new to this and trying out scrape_configs but no luck yet. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store it? Wouldn't it be enough to just query your original metric and use `label_replace` to rename metric and some labels?

Comment: Thanks for your response @markalex . Can `label_replace` do what I want to do? I thought it can modify only one label at a time. I want to add prefix to all the labels. If it's possible, then it will do the job.

Comment: You are correct, `label_replace` replaces only one label at time, but it can be nested. You'll need one for `__name__`, and one for each label you want to add prefix (or even two if you want to also drop original label)

Comment: Thanks @markalex. Can you please help me with it or point me to an article that discusses nested `label_replace`?

Comment: What do you mean? `label_replace(label_replace(kube_namespace_labels,"prefix_label1","$1","label1","(.*)"),"prefix_label2","$1","label2","(.*)")` will introduce two new labels based on old ones. Is that what you need?

Comment: I don't know what the labels will be at the time of executing the query. `label1` and `label2` were just examples. But to make it easier, let's say I want to replace `prefix1`  with `prefix2`.

Example, if the original metric is:
`kube_namespace_labels{namespace="ns1",prefix1_label1="value1",prefix1_label2="value2"}`

Then the result should be:
`kube_namespace_labels{namespace="ns1",prefix2_label1="value1",prefix2_label2="value2"}`

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to add an arbitrary prefix to all the labels of a particular time series. You can use [label_join](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_join) or [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) functions for creating new labels with additional prefix if you know beforehand the needed labels. For example, the following query copies `foo` label into `bar_foo` label for time series returned by `q` (e.g. it adds `bar_` prefix to `foo` label name):

```
label_join(q, "bar_foo", "", "foo")
```

P.S. If you need copying all the labels from one metric to another and adding the given prefix to all the copied labels, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76784172/274937).