# How to add namespace labels to pod labels in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to get the pods from the namespaces with particular labels.
So, I am trying to join these 2 metrics: `kube_pod_labels` and `kube_namespace_labels`.

I tried this query but it returns `kube_pod_labels` only:

`kube_pod_labels * on(namespace) group_left(kube_namespace_labels) kube_namespace_labels`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this exact metrics, but you `group_left` clause seems wrong: it should contain list of labels expected to be added to result. Consider this [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=go_build_info&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=up%20*%20on(instance)%20group_left(version)%20go_build_info&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h)

Comment: Thanks @markalex. Is there a way I can add all labels using `group_left`?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a way. And why do you need to "join" unknown number of labels?

Comment: The cluster Prometheus is doing remote write to a db. Another Prometheus instance reads the data from that db. There, I need to filter pod names based upon namespace labels.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus adds only the labels from `one`-side of `group_left()` / `group_right()` [operation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches), which are explicitly mentioned in the `on(...)` list. For example, the following query adds `foo` and `bar` labels from `kube_namespace_labels` to the returned `kube_pod_labels` time series:

```
kube_pod_labels * on(namespace) group_left(foo, bar) kube_namespace_labels
```

If you need the ability to join all the labels from one metric to another, then you can try Prometheus-like solution I work on - VictoriaMetrics. Starting from [v1.92.0](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/releases/tag/v1.92.0) release it supports the ability to specify `*` inside `group_left()` / `group_right()` in order to get all the labels from `one`-side. It also supports the ability to add a prefix for the added labels in order to avoid potential clash. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query adds all the labels from `kube_namespace_labels` to `kube_pod_labels` and prefixes these labels with `ns_`:

```
kube_pod_labels * on(namespace) group_left(*) prefix "ns_" kube_namespace_labels
```